# Python: merge data frame interval time

Tags: python, timestamp, dataframe

Hello I have two different dataframes.

```
df1 = 
id        time                     X           Y
266 2014-03-03 07:14:59.638703  48.788017   11.383924
267 2014-03-03 07:15:00.738946  48.788024   11.383919
269 2014-03-03 07:15:01.639143  48.788043   11.383909
270 2014-03-03 07:15:02.639365  48.788051   11.383892
```

and the second one

```
df2 =
      id2       time                   Val
    1679836 2014-03-03 07:14:59.390174  4
    1679837 2014-03-03 07:14:59.890167  7
    1679838 2014-03-03 07:15:00.390249  8
    1679841 2014-03-03 07:15:00.940196  7
```

I want to find when the value `val` and `X` and `Y` are very close in time, let say when the difference in time is of the order of 10 millisecond.

Comment: Are these Pandas dataframes?

Comment: Yes, they are Pandas dataframes

Comment: I'm confused about your question. Are you trying to merge the two dataframes and then groupBy a period of time? Also, could you post some code you've tried and an example of your expected output?

Comment: At the moment, I did:  `df1['time'] = df1['time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))` and `df2['time'] = df2['time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(microsecond=0))`. Finally I merged together `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['time'])`. But I am afraid to loose information in this way

Comment: Instead of replacing your 'time' column, you could create a new column with the less precise time, and then merge on / group by that column. That way you'd still have your original time column.

Comment: ok. How I can reduce the precision from, for instance, `2014-03-03 07:14:59.390174` to `2014-03-03 07:14:59.400000`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92987/discussion-between-jgloves-and-emax).